# C# How to hide specific cell using other's cell value in Datagrid

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid

I need some help! I want to hide the DataGridTemplateColumn whenever the
DatagridTextColumn value is not null. I've done the triggering part but it only applies to the whole row, I just want to apply the hiding on a single cell. Thanks.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status}"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="declined">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button x:Name="accept" Height="20" FontSize="10" Tag="{Binding Id}" Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=isAccept}" Content="Accept" Click="AcceptLeave"/>
                        <Button Height="20" FontSize="10" Tag="{Binding Id}" x:Name="decline" Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=isDecline}" Content="Decline" Click="DeclineLeave"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: So you are only wanting to show the columns that _contain_ null (which will just show empty columns/cells)?

Comment: I mean to use the Status Text Column as a reference. When the Status Column has a value I want to hide the DataGridTemplateColumn